# Image with multiple choice grid in google forms

Tags: google-forms

Can I put an image on left side and multiple-choice grid on right side of a question.If it is possible please explain me ASAP.I tried but it's representing like up and down,But I need on a page with landscape screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it with the wizard tool of Google Form, fortunately, a nice way to generate the form through HTML, and when you use HTML to generate Google Form, that will make you do whatever you like: adjust the layout the way you love, you may use your own CSS, anything can be doable.

Please follow instruction on this link below:

```
< https://codepen.io/learningcode/post/customize-a-google-form-for-your- 
website >
```

also, you may check the add-ons on Google Form and select the one that suites your requirements, there is a lot of tools which can help you, but I think the one I posted up is the best option to customize the way you like.

Comment: It is showing how to do Google forms for all type of questions, but I want to know how can I put an image and multiple grid on a page.

Comment: you can use ifame with in one page  , you can manipulate as you like then  , but as for google do not give this kind of customization until you do it this way or use add on apps

Comment: Thanks Ahmed Shahin